# C# How to get the assembly of pending changes during check in policy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I want to raise the assembly version number of a project by using a check in policy. How can I get the assembly by using CheckedPendingChanges? I get the filename but I don't know how to extract generically the assembly out of it so that I can manipulate the version number and to check it out.

```
this.PendingCheckin.PendingChanges.CheckedPendingChanges
```

I'm open minded for other approaches to raise the version number of a project where some code changes are inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with this approach, you could look for all .csproj (or whichever project format relevant to you) that contain that filename (you will need to care for relative vs absolute paths).

I would prefer the build system to be responsible for versions, triggered on specific paths to identify the project . I prefer an assembly version format like yyyy.MM.dd.revision. II have an example lying around for programatically stamping all assemblyinfo.cs files in a solution with a custom version through msbuild, which could be adapted to your needs. I will find it and post it when I reach home.